# Converting columns to row and updating

Tags: c#, sql-server

So, I have an excel file which contains my warehouse in column format and item codes in row format. In DB in my  table I have Warehouse codes and Item codes in row format . I need to update the stock(in excel present in column format) of each item with all the warehouses respectively. In C#(front end) I am able to achieve it by applying the loop. But the loop is getting executed for odd 2,25,000 times. It is taking about 10 hours to update the stock values of item codes with warehouses. So, I am proposing to get the warehouse codes as is from excel sheet and make the columns(Warehouse code) to rows. I am almost there , but as i said in my previous question I am getting the column's name but not its value. Please propose any solution.

Comment: Show us some sample data along with your actual table definitions.

Comment: Have you looked at using SSIS or using something like TPL in C#? Can you post the loop code

Comment: @christiandev : No, can you please give me the link for the same you are suggesting about.

Comment: @Ankur You would need to transform the data in SSIS, but here's an example http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205 and for the Parallel.ForEach http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer , wrote 2 while loops and was able to fine the column name and its value dynamically

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
declare @count int
declare @count1 int
set @count1 = (select min(srno) from TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE)
declare @f varchar(20)
declare @wh varchar(20)
SET @intFlag = 1
set @count = (select max(srno) from dbo.TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE)

declare @col_Count int
set @col_Count = (select count(*) NoOfColumns from SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE id= (Select id from SYSOBJECTS where name = 'TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE'))
--select @col_Count


declare @cnt int
set @cnt=4
--select @intFlag
--select @count1
--select @count
--select @cnt
--select @col_Count







while(@count1<=@count)
begin

    while(@cnt<=@col_Count-1)
        begin

            declare @whcode varchar(20)

            set @whcode=(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
            FROM Ecata_New.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            where Table_Name = 'TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE'  
            and COLUMN_NAME =(select whcode from dbo.temp_stock_map where func=(select func from dbo.temp_stock_map where sr_no=(@cnt-3))))
            --select @whcode
            DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)

            --SET @SQL = 'select ' + @whcode + ' from TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE where F1=(select F1 from dbo.TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE where srno='+convert(varchar,16091)+')'
            SET @SQL = 'select ' + @whcode + ' from TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE where srno='+convert(varchar,@count1)
            --print @SQL
            --EXEC (@SQL)
            declare @tab table
            (value1 varchar(20)) 
            insert into @tab EXEC (@SQL) 
            declare @value2 varchar(20)
            set @value2=(SELECT * from @tab)
            declare @final decimal(10,2)
            if(@value2 is null)
            set @final=0.00
            else
            set @final = @value2

        update dbo.tbl_wh_Itemwise
        set
        whItm_OP_STK_Qty=@final,
        whItm_Creation_DT=getdate()

        where 
        whItm_item_code=(select F1 from dbo.TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE where srno=@count1) 
        and 
        whItm_wh_code=(select func from dbo.temp_stock_map where sr_no=(@cnt-3))
        delete from @tab

set @cnt=@cnt+1
end

set @cnt =4
set @count1=@count1+1
end
```